# Hide the y-axis line from the bar chart using plotly() in r

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am visualizing a horizontal bar chart using `plot_ly()`. The axis line for the x-axis is not displayed but is displayed for the y-axis. I am not sure of how to hide the axis line for a bar chart.

The dataframe used is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame("Grade" = c(9,10,11,12), "totalHours" = c(93,81,7,96),
                 "Count" = c(30,16,1,14), "average" = c(3.100,5.062,7.000,6.857))
```

The `plot_ly()` call used for visualizing is as follows:

```
plot_ly(df, x=df$average, y=df$Grade, 
        type="bar", color=~Grade, orientation = 'h') %>%
  add_text(text=round(df$average), hoverinfo='none', textposition = 'auto', showlegend = FALSE,
           textfont=list(size=12, color="black")) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE),showlegend=FALSE)
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the computer still understands it as `xaxis` even if it is turned. I hope this does the trick for you:

```
Noax <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = FALSE,
  showgrid = FALSE
)

plot_ly(df, x=df$average, y=df$Grade, 
        type="bar", color=~Grade, orientation = 'h') %>%
  add_text(text=round(df$average), hoverinfo='none', textposition = 'auto', showlegend = FALSE,
           textfont=list(size=12, color="black")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = Noax)
```

[image]